# Specifying contingencies for a max(date) function in Redshift query

Tags: sql, amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift

I'm trying to determine when customers don't login during a calendar week, when was the last time they did login. The starting dataset looks something like this:

```
User_Name   Login_Date  Week_Ending
Bobisaur    1/1/2019    1/5/2019
Bobisaur    1/3/2019    1/5/2019
Bobisaur    3/5/2019    3/9/2019
Bobisaur    3/24/2019   3/30/2019
Bobisaur    4/1/2019    4/6/2019
```

Now for the week ending `1/12/2019` and so forth, there would be no logins for the customer `Bobisaur` What I would like to do is end up with a dataset that looks like this:

```
User_Name   Week_Ending (for weeks with no login)   Days Since Last Login (as of week ending date)
Bobisaur    1/12/2019    7 
Bobisaur    1/19/2019    14 
Bobisaur    1/26/2019    21 
Bobisaur    2/2/2019     28 
Bobisaur    2/9/2019     35 
Bobisaur    2/16/2019    42 
Bobisaur    2/23/2019    49 
Bobisaur    3/2/2019     56 
Bobisaur    3/16/2019    11 
Bobisaur    3/23/2019    18 
Bobisaur    4/13/2019    12
```

This would be filtering down onto a list of weeks for the user where they did not have a login and having a column for how many days it's been since they last logged in, as of that specific week-ending date.

I'm able to get the `Week_Ending` dates where there is no login activity, however, I got stuck on calculating "Days Since Last Login (as of week-ending date)." What I tried doing was using `(Week_Ending - max(Login_Date))` and then specify a having clause with `max(Login_Date) <= Week_Ending`.

However, this basically removed all rows where the `Week_Ending` value was earlier than the max `Login_Date`.

Any help would be vastly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Could you please share the query that you used to get your intermediate result? Probably easier, to just adapt it.

Comment: Here's final part of the query -- select calendar_week_ending, (calendar_week_ending - max(login_dater)) as days_since_last_login, user_name
from db
group by 1
having max(login_date) <= calendar_week_ending -- Because the Having clause specifies the max(login_date), which is 4/1/2019 in this case, needs to be prior to the calendar_week_ending, the only week_ending (where there isn't a login) that qualifies is 4/13.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The resulting query seems complicated, but it's not so bad:

- `intput_raw` - whatever you pasted in the question
- `input` - swapped `login_data` with respective `week_ending`
- `cal` - calendar table with consecutive Saturdays (your definition of *week ending* ). In Redshift the only way to *generate* rows is to `SELECT`. Here I generate 25 rows by cross joining input with itself to get 25 (5x5) consecutive Saturdays. `CROSS JOIN` can be changed to `SELECT row_number() over () from arbitrary table limit 25`.
- `cal_usrs` - table with all the users and all Saturdays
- `output_raw` - the heart of the calculation - first `JOIN`  `cal_usrs` with `input` and use window function to get the *days since last login*. Since it's not possible to filter on a column with is a result of a window function (and your desired output does not have rows with `0`) there is a final `SELECT`.
- *final `SELECT`* - selects only what we're interested in.

The query:

```
with input_raw as (
  select 'Bobisaur' as username, '1/1/2019'::date as login_date
  union all
  select 'Bobisaur', '1/3/2019'::date
  union all
  select 'Bobisaur', '3/5/2019'::date
  union all
  select 'Bobisaur', '3/24/2019'::date
  union all
  select 'Bobisaur', '4/1/2019'::date
), input as (
  select
         username,
         -- in your example weeks ends on saturday hence Monday + 5 days
         date_trunc('week', login_date) + interval '5 days' as week_ending
  from input_raw
), cal as (
  -- this will create a table with consecutive Saturdays
  select
         date_trunc('week', '12/1/2018'::date) + interval '5 days'+ 7 * row_number() over () as week_ending
  -- can be changed to 'from arbitrary table limit 25' or whatever time window you wish
  from input_raw a cross join input_raw b --this will produce 25 rows

), cal_usrs as (
  select * from cal cross join (select distinct username from input) as u
  -- this is very important - you want to have all weeks with all users
), output_raw as (
  select cal_usrs.username,
         cal_usrs.week_ending,
         max(input.week_ending)
             over (partition by cal_usrs.username order by cal_usrs.week_ending rows between unbounded preceding and current row ) as last_login_week,
         extract('days' from cal_usrs.week_ending - last_login_week) as days_since_last_login
  from input
         right join cal_usrs using (username, week_ending)
)
select
  username,
  to_char(week_ending, 'MM/DD/YYYY') as week_anding,
  days_since_last_login
from output_raw
where days_since_last_login <> 0 -- your example did not contain 0 rows
order by week_ending
```

the result looks like (i think you made some miscalculation in your example after March 16th):

```
    username    week_ending days_since_last_login
    Bobisaur    01/12/2019  7
    Bobisaur    01/19/2019  14
    Bobisaur    01/26/2019  21
    Bobisaur    02/02/2019  28
    Bobisaur    02/09/2019  35
    Bobisaur    02/16/2019  42
    Bobisaur    02/23/2019  49
    Bobisaur    03/02/2019  56
    Bobisaur    03/16/2019  7
    Bobisaur    03/30/2019  7
    Bobisaur    04/13/2019  7
    Bobisaur    04/20/2019  14
    Bobisaur    04/27/2019  21
    Bobisaur    05/04/2019  28
    Bobisaur    05/11/2019  35
    Bobisaur    05/18/2019  42
    Bobisaur    05/25/2019  49
```